# Hacer consulta con varios datos en base de datos Access con Java

Tags: java, eclipse, ms-access, sql, conversión-de-tipos

Tengo una base de datos en Access con varios tipos de campo, Unos de Texto corto y otros en enteros.
Al hacer Consultas por medio de UcanAccess puedo recoger los valores de los campos de Texto Corto
pero, al momento de leer un campo en formato Entero o que tenga varios valores( EJ: Campo = Persona, Valor = Hombre;Mujer) me marca error o también al leer el campo Aro que contiene solo enteros

```
public String[] AñadeValoresJCombobox(String[] Lista,String Tipo) {


        int Tamaño = 0;
        Tamaño=ConoceTamañoLista(Tamaño,Tipo);  //Conoce cuantos datos tiene el campo
        Lista = new String[Tamaño];//Crea un arreglo de strings
        Tamaño=0;
        try {

            String sql = "select DISTINCT "+Tipo+" from Bicicletas";   //Tipo serian los distintos campos sin repeticion
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet Resultado = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while(Resultado.next()) {
                Lista[Tamaño]=Resultado.getString(1);  //El resultado de la consulta lo guarda
                Tamaño++;

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Lista;

}

private int ConoceTamañoLista(int Tamaño,String Tipo){

    try {

        String sql = "select DISTINCT "+Tipo+" from Bicicletas";
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet Resultado = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while(Resultado.next()) {
            System.out.println("Tipo:"+Resultado.getString(1));
            Tamaño++;

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return Tamaño;

}
```

El error es el siguente:
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: tipo de datos incompatibles en la conversión: from SQL type OTHER to java.lang.String, value: instance of org.hsqldb.types.JavaObjectData

Mi intencion es recoger los valores y añadirlos a un JComboBox por eso retorna una Lista de strings.
Tipo seria siendo un String con el Nombre del Campo

Comment: Que errores te marca???

Comment: Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: tipo de datos incompatibles en la conversión: from SQL type OTHER to java.lang.String, value: instance of org.hsqldb.types.JavaObjectData

Comment: usa el boton [edit].. donde tira ese error? cuando haces que cosa? tene en cuenta que no sabemos nada de tu sistema...

Comment: El error aparece cuando intento leer un campo de varios valores, solo puedo leer campos enteros y de texto corto Especificamente aca : Lista[Tamaño]=Resultado.getString(1);

Comment: Como es un campo de varios valores? las bases de datos no tienen campos con varios valores. Y getstring solo funciona si el tipo de campo es string, si es numerico no funciona...

Comment: He usado el Asistente para busqueda de Access para que al momento en que defina un valor de una celda de un campo, aparezca una lista desplegable con los valores que deseo y que solo se permiten, active la opcion de poder marcar varios valores. Corrigeme si esto es tener varios valores en una celda de un campo o no, por que necesito que se lean esos 2 valores y en mi programa solo puedo leer uno

Comment: no. eso es una asistencia de access, pero en el campo se guarda el valor id relacionado de la otra tabla. Salvo que sea otra de las opciones de access que solo permiten una lista de valores, pero en el campo se guarda un solo valor.

Comment: Ah vale comprendo, tendre que desactivar la opcion de varios valores en access, y crear datos separados. Gracias por tu tiempo